# Why is the performance of calling memcpy in Linux system poor and fluctuating

Tags: memcpy

The source memory of memcpy is applied by RDMA thread, and the destination memory is applied by spdk thread, and the memory is copied in spdk thread. Both RDMA and spdk threads are in polling mode and are bound with CPU core (the same NUMA node). GCC is version 9.6. It is found that the time consumption of memcpy is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYWzx.png)

The memory size of the copy is 4KB. The time consumption of a single memcpy call fluctuates between 1 and 50 US. Why is the time consuming so high? May I ask where there is a problem?

Comment: And what's your quesiton about this? Please share more details, like a specific question, the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have revised the description

Comment: I would suggest you read [this article by Ulrich Drepper](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf) and profile your software. Once you have a precise cause, we may be able to help you.